# R Parallel computing: select which objects to be distributed into cores

Tags: r, parallel-processing, snow, doparallel, parallel-foreach

I have a question related to r-parallel computing. I am using something like:

```
cl.tmp = makeCluster(10, type="SOCK")
registerDoParallel(cl.tmp)
AA <- foreach(i = 1:48, .inorder = TRUE, .combine = rbind, .verbose=TRUE) %dopar% {
# A function that depends on some selected objects in current environment
}
stopCluster(cl.tmp)
```

How to identify some particular objects in the current environment to be distributed into processor cores and so be used for some functions? I do not need R to copy the whole objects in the environment into different cores, but only some selected objects. In my project, I have big R objects and I do not need to copy/distribute them into cores, to avoid ram problems. Is there a solution for that?

Thanks

Comment: Assuming that you know which objects are to be exported (that's not entirely clear from your question), you can insert something like `clusterExport(cl.tmp, c(obj1, obj2, ...), globalenv())` on line 2

Comment: Thanks.. I will try this

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: [reading global variables using foreach in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18028452/reading-global-variables-using-foreach-in-r)

Only variables referenced inside the foreach loop are copied from the global environment.